# After selector.selete(), selectedKeys() returns empty

Tags: java, sockets, nio

When using Java NIO, I got some problems.

I need to **change the `interestOps` of a `key`**. I found here are two ways to do it.

**First** is done by invoking `key.interestOps()`:

```
key.interestOps(OP_READ)
```

However I encountered with very tricky *thread-safe* issues in this way:

```
key.interestOps(OP_WRITE);
sl.select();  
Iterator iter = sl.selectedKeys().iterator();
log(iter.toArray().length); // Sometimes, I got 0 here!
```

The interesting thing is I got 0 sometimes in log (But sometimes it just works well). But there is no explicit modification of key in other threads. I can't understand what happened between the `line2` and `line3`.

**Another** way is to `register` again:

The problem is the new return `key` lost his buffer:

```
key = sockChannel.register(selector, OP_WRITE);
key.attach(buf);
sockChannel.register(selector, OP_READ);
key.attachment();// nullExcetion here!
```

Of course this can be fixed by reassigning the buffer, but I'm sure things can be better.

Any insights?

Comment: The first is preferable, as you conserve the key, but there is no such thing as 'Iterator.toArray().' What's the real code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I should say the thread safety issue in Java NIO is sooooo tricky. It's better to avoid it instead of to figure it out. That is the philosophy advocated by the author of *Rox Java NIO Tutorial* http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/, which is an excellent tutorial for green hands on NIO. Lots of tips and principles are very useful. I'd personally recommend this tutorial to everyone who'd like to dig into Java NIO. Read it and you can learn a lot.

Comment: The ROX NIO tutorial is garbage. Guy doesn't even know that closing the channel cancels the key, and he invents a lot of non-existent difficulties about other things as well.